# Easy way to add a break to Y-axis in barchart() of lattice in R?

Tags: r

I have been searching and could find no straightforward solution. Let us consider the plot below:

```
library("lattice")
barchart(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,10)^2~c(1,2,3,4,5,6,10), horiz=FALSE, ylim=c(0,120))
```

Would please anyone know a simple way of adding a break on Y-axis, say, between 50-80? If possible while adding a -//- mark on that axis indicating such break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are free to use another package than `lattice`, the following straigthforward code could do the trick for you using the `gap.barplot()` function from the `plotrix` package

```
require(plotrix)
gap.barplot( c(1,2,3,4,5,6,10)^2, 
             gap=c(50, 80),
             main = "Barplot with Gap",
             ylab= "Y"
             )
```

This yields the following plot:
[image]

Please let me know whether this is what you wanted.

Comment: In case I am not able to go about this within lattice I shall do your solution, thanks! In principle I am trying to diversify packages to a minimum plus I believe there should be a solution in lattice which would give me a classical -//- demarcation !.. Will wait a bit longer here